# How to return just the target entity with JPARepository

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have multiple parent-child entities set up as such.

```
public class Brigade {
  // Ids

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "brigade", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonManagedReference
  private List<Battalion> battalionList;

 // other columns
}

public class Battalion {
  // Ids

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "BRIGADE_ID")
  @JsonBackReference
  private Brigade brigade;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "battalion", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonManagedReference
  private List<Company> companyList;

  // other columns
}

public class Company {
  // Ids

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "BATTALION_ID")
  @JsonBackReference
  private Battalion battalion;

  // other columns
}
```

At the front end, I have a page to display a table of battalions for user to select to view the details. This page relies on a RESTful API, with the repository and service class set up as such.

```
public interface BattalionRepository extends JpaRepository<Battalion, Long> { }

public class BattalionService {

  @Autowired
  private BattalionRepository battRepository;

  public List<Battalion> getAllBattalions() {
    return List<Battalion> battRepository.findAll();
  }

  // other stuff
}
```

My issue is that JPARepository's `.findAll()` method will return not just the list of battalion entries, but also the parent brigade entity that the battalion is linked to, and all the associated child companies that each battalion contains. It bloats the JSON data (I don't need all those details for the table) and makes it incredibly hard to read when debugging, not to mention the security concerns with just dumping all that data onto the client.

How do I get the JPARepository to return ***just*** the target entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) you can fetch selective properties by declaring your own interface representing selective attributes and writing you own query method. Of-course there are multiple ways of writing the interface. Take a look at the examples shared in documentation.